# Date query in Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01427

I have a table where there `are 5 columns` let say `a,b,c,d,tran_date`.

I want to generate a  query to find out the minimum tran_date for every  `a,b,c,d` in the table.

Any help how this can be done.

EDIT:The result of this query needs to be subtracted from a single date which is a  result from the query:

```
  select ref_date from ref_table
```

How this can be done because the error `ORA-01427: single row subquery returns more than one row`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the minimum tran_date for every a,b,c,d in the table'? Could you give some example data and what the output should be? Also what flavour of SQL you are using would help.

Comment: @CamJackson I am using Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try something like

```
SELECT  a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        MIN(tran_date) MIN_tran_date
FROM    Table
GROUP BY    a,
            b,
            c,
            d
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @astander's answer to include the additional subtratction requirement:

```
select a, b, c, d,
    min(tran_date) as min_tran_date,
    min(tran_date) - (select ref_date from ref_table) as diff
from my_table
group by a, b, c, d;
```

Note that the `diff` may be positive or negataive, depending on whether the `ref_date`is before all `tran_date` values, after them all, or somewhere in the middle.

If you're only interested in certain `diff` values - say, where the minimnum `tran_date` is after the `ref_date` - you can add a `having` clause to filter the results; in this case:

```
having min(tran_date) - (select ref_date from ref_table) > 0
```

or perhaps to be clearer:

```
having min(tran_date) > (select ref_date from ref_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, Min(SomeDate) FROM Foo GROUP BY A
```